# Dynamically creating table rows and div's using document.createElement(“div”);

Tags: javascript

I am trying to dynamically parse JSON data and populate the data in rows in an html table.

I wrote the following test and don't really see any reason why it should not work.

EDIT:corrected the two syntax errors.

```
<tohead>

<script>

var zoho = "?({"Products":[{"model":"UN55F8000BFXZA","phone":"1234567890","price":"2999.99","manufacturer":"Samsung","purchaseDate":"2013-07-26"}]});"

$(document).ready(function(){
   processRecord(zoho);
});

function addRow(inc) {

   VAR table = document.getElementById("dataTable");

   VAR rowCount = table.rows.length;
   VAR row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

   VAR cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   VAR element1 = document.createElement("div");
   element1.id = 'manufacturer' + inc;
   element1.class = "text";
   cell1.appendChild(element1);

   VAR cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   VAR element2 = document.createElement("div");
   element2.id = 'purchaseDate' + inc;
   element2.class = "text";
   element2.align = "center";
   cell2.appendChild(element2);

   VAR cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
   VAR element3 = document.createElement("div");
   element3.id = 'endingDate' + inc;
   element3.class = "text";
   element3.align = "center";
   cell3.appendChild(element3);

};

function processRecord(zoho_data){
   for (var i=0; i<zoho_data.length; i++){

   addRow(i);

   var phonenumber = zoho_data.Products[i].phone;
   var zmanufacturer = zoho_data.Products[i].manufacturer;
   var zmodel = zoho_data.Products[i].model;
   var zpurchaseDate = zoho_data.Products[i].purchaseDate;

   document.getElementById('manufacturer' + i).appendChild(zmanufacturer);
   document.getElementById('purchaseDate' + i).appendChild(zpurchaseDate);
   document.getElementById('endingDate' + i).appendChild(d1);
   }
};

</script>

</tohead>

<HTML>
<HEAD>

</HEAD>
<BODY>


<TABLE id="dataTable" width="546">

</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

EDIT: In response to the comments I have reduced the complexity of the code above to narrow down the issue.  The code below is the new code with just the createElement loop.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   addRow();
});

function addRow() {
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        VAR table = document.getElementById("dataTable");

        VAR rowCount = table.rows.length;
        VAR row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        VAR cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        VAR element1 = document.createElement("div");
        element1.setAttribute('id', 'manufacturer' + i);
        element1.setAttribute(class, 'text');
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        VAR cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        VAR element2 = document.createElement("div");
        element2.setAttribute('id', 'purchaseDate' + i);
        element2.setAttribute(class, 'text');
        element2.setAttribute(align, 'center');
        cell2.appendChild(element2);

        VAR cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        VAR element3 = document.createElement("div");
        element3.setAttribute('id', 'endingDate' + i);
        element3.setAttribute(class, 'text');
        element3.setAttribute(align, 'center');
        cell3.appendChild(element3);
    }
};
</script>     
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="546" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>boo</td>
    </tr>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What research/debugging have you performed? Can you narrow down the issue to a testcase? And what on earth is `<tohead>`?

Comment: -1 for not having opened the debugging console and noticed the syntax error (and there's not just one) gazing at you

Comment: The expected result in this case would be one row in the table containing the values Samsung UN55F8000BFXZA 2013-07-26.  `<tohead>` is just a tag that places the script inside the <HEAD> HTML tag.  Not really necessary in this example, but not hurting anything either.

Comment: First, please don't change the code in a question. You might invalidate some answers. Second, you didn't "correct the two syntax errors". You corrected two reference errors (valid syntax referring to non-existing variables), but you left at least one syntax error in (the definition of `zoho`) and your HTML is still invalid (unless preprocessed by a server-side technology I don't know). Not even Google has heard of `tohead`.

Comment: see my post below with the correction of the zoho variable.  You are hung up by the <tohead>, and it is irrelevant to the issue (I ran it again to just make sure).  <tohead> does locate all code in those tags to the HEAD.

Comment: Two syntax issues in the code above that caused it to fail:  Attributes missing '', and var was in all caps (I copied this code from another site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone who might see this and have a similar concern.  The correct code is below.  I am passing in the function data returned in JSON format parsing it, and writing it to dynamically created "div"s, inside dynamically created table rows.

```
function processData(zoho_data){

    $.each(zoho_data.Products, function() {

        var phonenumber = this.phone;
        var zmanufacturer = this.manufacturer;
        var zmodel = this.model;
        var zpurchaseDate = this.purchaseDate;

        var d1 = Date.parse(zpurchaseDate).add(4).year().toString('yyyy-MM-dd');

        var table = document.getElementById("datatable");

        var row = table.insertRow(-1);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
        var element1 = document.createElement("div");
        element1.setAttribute('class', 'text');
        cell1.innerHTML = zmanufacturer + " " + zmodel;
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("div");
        element2.setAttribute('class', 'text');
        element2.setAttribute('align', 'center');
        cell2.innerHTML = zpurchaseDate;
        cell2.appendChild(element2);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
        var element3 = document.createElement("div");
        element3.setAttribute('class', 'text');
        element3.setAttribute('align', 'center');
        cell3.innerHTML = d1;
        cell3.appendChild(element3);
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `zoho` string is not an object, but a string, and as it starts with `?(` it is not valid JSON. It is not even valid Javascript — just look at those errant quotation marks.

You need to fix your JSON so that it is valid JSON, and then you need to convert your JSON string into a Javascript object.

Then, you need to fix `document.getElementById(dataTable)` because no such variable `dataTable` exists in your program. Did you mean the string `"dataTable"`?

Comment: The string set in the zoho variable might not be the best formatted JSON but it is that none the less.  It is was is returned from a Zoho Creator call that I have used in several other scripts and is working and is parseable.  Instead of putting the entire API call that returns the JSON, I just set it as the variable zoho. Your comment on `dataTable` is correct and should have been "dataTable"

Comment: @Neil: Call it what you will: that is _not_ valid JSON. JSON never begins with `?(`. Ever. http://json.org http://jsonlint.com

Comment: @NeilW. not to mention the unescaped double quotes enclosed in a double-quoted string

Comment: That wasn't the issue.  Formatted the JSON (@json.org) and still getting the same result.  Just to clarify I tested removing all of the appendChild statements in the processRecord function.  That essentially means that there is no writing of the text data, and the resultant table should have had one empty div written. `var zoho = JSON.parse({\"Products\":[{\"model\":\"UN55F8000BFXZA\",\"phone\":\"2488359400\",\"price\":\"2999.99\",\"manufacturer\":\"Samsung\",\"purchaseDate\":\"2013-07-26\"}]});`

Comment: @NeilW.: That presupposes that there was only _one_ issue. As I already indicated, you have several in your code. That you have fixed one doesn't mean you have fixed the others, and just because there are others doesn't mean that fixing this wasn't a requirement.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Agreed.  I simplified the code above to remove the whole parsing and writing to the div segment.

Answer (score 1):

`appendChild` only works with actual DOM type one nodes. Since it looks like you're just appending string values, try using `textContent =`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

If you want to append them as their own elements, you'll need to use: `document.createElement`  so that appendChild will work (since it belongs to the Node object).

Comment: Correct. There are shims that make it incredibly easy to use, however. http://eligrey.com/blog/post/textcontent-in-ie8

Comment: @JanDvorak, yeah, his answer came through while I was typing mine so before I hit enter I edited mine to just include the appendChild spec.

Comment: You should probably mention [document.createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) as the proper way to create a text node, not `textContent` ?

Comment: I also tried the jQuery:`$("#phone+i").text(phonenumber);
 $("#manufacturer+i").text(zmanufacturer + " " + zmodel);
 $("#purchaseDate+i").text(zpurchaseDate);
 $("#endingDate+i").text(d1);`  But I don't think the incremental div id is the correct syntax.  Regardless I don't think the issue is with that as I have tried it without the append to see if the table rows and div's were created dynamically.

Comment: @adeneo If you want your text to be returned as a node (like when using childNodes [it will display in console as '#text']), then you're absolutely right. That is assuming, however that OP wanted the text to be parseable via a nodeList and to not simply reference the containing node to fetch/update its contents (which is what I interpreted).

Comment: @NeilW. When you use jQuery or anything else to fetch DOM nodes, it will return an array of matched elements (an empty array if no match). So doing something like: `var el = $('div'); el[0].appendChild(foo);` is completely ok. You are correct that your above syntax is also incorrect. You would want to change: `document.getElementById('manufacturer' + i)` to `document.getElementById('manufacturer')[i]`. UNLESS you specifically call them `id="manufacturer0"` in the DOM.

Comment: Oh boy -> `document.getElementById('manufacturer')[i]` <- really! ID's are unique, and that does not select `manufacturer1` !

Comment: That is my interpretation of the code `element1.id = 'manufacturer' + inc;` where inc is the iteration passed into the function addRow.  Therefore I would need the iteration of each id in the appendChild to have the format manufacturer0 ...

Comment: Oh, I see all of the `createElement` blocks in `addRow`. Your targeting syntax is correct. You may want to check the DOM after that function to ensure the Id's are as you expect. If not, try. `element1.setAttribute('id', 'manufacturer'+inc).` Also, ignore my above statement of :`document.getElementById('manufacturer')[i]` @adeneo is correct, to do that with Id's is completely silly. I was focusing too much on index accessor syntax and not the validity of that specific line.